# Denying repetitions of same random sequences

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

For example we have any number from 0 to 11, and I need to repeat the process a couple of times (my intention is too complicated to explain so just bear with me):

```
        Random ran = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            int n = ran.Next(0, 10);
            //......
        }
```

However, application mustn't ever repeat the same random sequence. How can i do this? I thought about forcingly excluding previous seeds each iteration, but i don't know how to manipulate seeds. Any idea? Also, first number choice MUST not be pseudo-random. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must it not ever repeat the same sequence? How long is the sequence that can’t be repeated? And what do you mean by “must not be pseudo-random”? Your intention may be complicated to explain, but context *is* necessary to answer this.

Comment: @Ry- i'll try my best. I have two integer arrays with 20 integers each. In each iteration, one random integer from random one of those arrays must be picked. When they are all picked, cycle repeats, but it mustn't repeat in the same way. 

Sequence length is obviously 40 then (20+20).

When i say that first number choice must not be pseudo random that means it can't have designated seed, it must be true random.

Comment: Can you just use a CSPRNG then? Uniformly random selections from a set of 40! have no chance of repeating.

Comment: How different do you need your sequences to be?  You could pick the first number to be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. with the RNG generating the rest of each sequence.  That way each sequence is guaranteed to be different because all the first numbers are different, even in the unlikely event the other numbers are in the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The `Random` object has another constructor `public Random(int Seed)` where you can provide the seed value so you can change the seed value every time to get a different sequence.

Check also the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_) that describes everything in detail.